# Python class - chaining instance methods

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I've started to build my `class` in this fashion (more like a regular `function`):

`ex 1`

```
  class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self,user):
        Parent.__init__(self, user)     

        search = api.search() 
        filter = api.filter(search)
        output = api.output(filter)

        return output
```

this way I could run:

```
movies = Child('John')
```

and get my final output.

Then, I broke my `global api methods` into `instance methods` in order to have more control of data:

`ex 2`

```
  class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self,user):
        Parent.__init__(self, user)     

    def search_api(self):
       search = api.search() 
       return search    

    def filter_api(self, search):
       filter = api.filter(search)
       return filter

    def output(self, filter):
       output = api.output(filter)  
       return output
```

and now I have to break it in different instances, to get the final output:

```
test = Child('John')
search = test.search_api()
filter = test.filter_api(search)
out = test.output(filter)

print (out)
```

Is there a `decorator` or `built-in method` that allows me to chain all `instance methods` so that `ex2` can be run in one shot (instantiation)?

Comment: You mean `test.output(test.filter_api(test.search_api()))`?

Comment: How come in `ex2` you aren't using the arguments in your methods? I can't imagine it would do what you wanted in that case.

Comment: This makes no sense. Your `__init__` is superfluous because it does nothing more than the superclass' does, and none of the methods ever use `self`, so they could just as well be perfectly normal functions.

Comment: And besides never using any of arguments of the methods, your original example tried returning something from `__init__` - that doesn't work either.

Comment: @RandomDavis I am. I've edited it now, sorry.

Comment: Best seems to be to do `output = api.output(api.filter(api.search()))` and forget about the class. And move that call to `api`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the magic stuff  if you need to make objects behave like function calls you should implement `__call__` instead of just packing everything in the constructor.:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self,user):
        Parent.__init__(self, user)
        self.myuser = user


    def search_api(self):
       search = api.search() 
       return search    

    def filter_api(self, search):
       filter = api.filter()
       return filter

    def output(self, filter): 
       return output

    def __call__(self,user):
        search = self.search_api()
        filter = self.filter_api(search)
        return self.output(filter)
```

And now you can:

```
a = Child('Joe')
print(a())
```

Comment: You'll get `TypeError: __init__() should return None`

Comment: Yep, that's what I get for posting without reviewing my answers, edited the answer. Thanks @RencoGerlich

Comment: all answers were valid, but I think this is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is the builder pattern so you could write `output = Search().filter().get_output()` or something like that.

For this to work, you need to return the builder object from all the "intermediate" methods:

```
class Search(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # apply args, kwargs

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # apply args, kwargs
        self.filters.append(...)
        return self

    def paginate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # apply args, kwargs
        self.pagination = ...
        return self

    def get_output(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # apply args, kwargs
        # build the search, find output ...
        return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Some helpers to make it compile:

```
class API:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return API()
    def __call__(self, x=1):
        return 42

api = API()

class Parent(object):
     def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
```

Doing all steps in `process` method:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, user):
        super().__init__(user)     

    def search_api(self):
        search = api.search() 
        return search    

    def filter_api(self, search):
        filter = api.filter()
        return filter

    def output(self, filter):   
        return api.output

    def process(self):
        res = self.search_api() 
        res = self.filter_api(res)
        return self.output(res)
```

allows you to do all in one line:

```
movies = Child('John').process()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__call__()`. I know it's not the same, but perhaps it might be better than your `ex2`:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, user):
        Parent.__init__(self, user)

    def search_api(self):
        search = api.search() 
        return search    

    def filter_api(self, search):
        filter = api.filter(search)
        return filter

    def output(self, filter):
        output = api.output(filter)  
        return output

    def __call__(self):
        search = self.search_api()
        filter = self.filter_api(search)
        return self.output(filter)
```

Then, you can do:

```
c = Child("john")
output = c()
```